# How to open new JFrame when clicking JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have a simple problem with opening a new `JFrame` called `focalSumFrame` while clicking on `JButton` called `focalSum`. I am working in netBeans IDE. My code looks like this:

```
private void focalSumActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    focalSumFrame.pack();
    focalSumFrame.setVisible(true);   
}
```

Comment: Do you already have an existing Jframe you are using? If so you might want to use [JDialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead of more JFrames.

Comment: 1) The exact same way you'd do it in Eclipse or coding using a text editor.  (I.E. Your IDE has nothing to do with this)  2) Don't do that!  Show extra content in a `CardLayout` or `JDialog` etc. 3) If you achieve it, that is when the 'complex problems' will kick in.  ;)

Comment: the JButton belongs to focalSumFrame ?!

Comment: in which way JDialog is better than JFrame?

Comment: Can you post all the code of this class?

Comment: @FGraviton: focalSumFrame is a JFrame which I want to open by clicking on JButton designed in an existing JFrame (main JFrame of my app).

Comment: my problem is solved by using JDialog, thanks!

Comment: @MichalB I'll go ahead, or Andrew can make a post so that you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more efficent and easier to use [JDialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and/or [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for alternative pages of your program. Creating other `JFrames` to use as your pop-ups is a very ineffective way to go about what you're trying to do.

[JDialog](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1220__JDialog.htm) Information

[Card Layout](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1208/java-card-layout-manager-swing/) Information